# Syntax or Code to detect a user mouseclick outside of a button/ picture. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple game in a C# Windows Forms app. I have took a picture appear using a picture box and if the user presses it in time they get a point, I'm looking for a way to take detect if they click outside of the picture, how I can then take a point away.

I have my click event with the integer scores, and I use score++. Is there a function to determine if they clicked anywhere outside the bounds of the picture box? Thanks.

I have tried searching for an inbounds method, but I have not found one that has worked. I have tried to read previous posts but I could not find a line of code or method that worked so far.

Comment: I'm assuming that you know how to handle clicks inside your picture box (by wiring up a `Click` (or `MouseDown` or whatever) handler and doing the work in the handler. Everything on the form, and the form itself works the same way. If all you ave on the form is the picture box, then everything outside the picture box will be handled by the form. If you have other controls you need to decide whether you want to wire them up too

Comment: You're literally asking for code so why use the designer tag? Removed. Please use only relevant tags.

Comment: As suggested, if they're clicking outside the `PictureBox` then they're clicking on something else, so you simply handle the same event that you're already handling for the `PictureBox` for that other control(s). A form is a control too.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by handling the click event on the form itself and then checking whether the click coordinates fall within the bounds of the picture box or not. If the click is outside the bounds of the picture box, you can decrement the score using `score -- ;` I hope this was helpful.